# An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application'].Why do i get this error in android studio (Artic fox version)?

Tags: java, android, gradle

**Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.1.1. Current version is 4.4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/rasil/.gradle/daemon/4.4.1/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-6.1.1-all.zip**

> I already make distributionUrl to gradle-6.1.1 as shown in below but it still shows the error.I clean the project and rebuild it.I also synced the project but still not working

```
//This is gradle-wrapper-properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME


//This is my dependencies in gradle scripts
```

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'

[image: This is the error of android studio terminal]

Comment: That might be stupid question, but did you sync the project after updating the distributionUrl? And you should ignore the path that's being shown in the error message. The wrapper version should be updated in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. `.gradle` directory is temporary one, you shouldn't change anything there

Comment: yes i have synced the project but still error occured .

Comment: Have you updated the proper gradle-wrapper.properties?